# C++ struct and typdef

Tags: c++

I am not sure about the title because I don't know what it is really about.

I was trying to understand the code in the link below.

[Color Based Particle Filter](https://bitbucket.org/kschluff/particle_tracker)

I generally understand what the program does, but I couldn't figure out "state.h". What does this code do? Especially the "typedef", "State_" and "pp" parts look stranger to me.

I will put some of the code here for clarity reasons.

```
struct StateData;
struct State_;
typedef State_ (*State)(StateData&);
struct State_
{
    State_( State pp ) : p( pp ) { }
    operator State()
    {
        return p;
    }
    State p;
};

State_ state_start(StateData& d);
State_ state_selecting(StateData& d);
State_ state_initializing(StateData& d);
State_ state_tracking(StateData& d);
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concisely: `State` is an alias for function pointer.`State_` is a wrapper class that has a `State` member, and is implicitly convertible into that `State`.

The reason why `State_` wrapper is needed, is because there is no way to express a function that returns a pointer to a function of the same type. The wrapper gets rid of the self-reference.

---

Line by line:

```
struct StateData;
```

A forward declaration of a class `StateData`.

```
struct State_;
```

A forward declaration of a class `State_`.

```
typedef State_ (*State)(StateData&);
```

This one is a bit tricky. It defines `State` as a type alias for a function pointer that can point to a function that returns a `State_` and takes a `StateData&` as an argument. The functions declared at the end of the snippet can be pointed by a function pointer of this type.

In my opinion, the chosen name is very confusing considering that there is already a `State_` class. While I'm usually against hungarian notation, I would recommend to always apply a suffix or prefix to denote a function pointer, say `state_fun` or `state_handler` or `state_callback`,

```
struct State_
{
```

This starts the definition of `State_` calss.

```
    State_( State pp ) : p( pp ) { }
```

This defines a constructor for the class. The argument is of the function pointer type that was defined earlier. It initializes the member that will be declared shortly.

```
    operator State()
    {
        return p;
    }
```

A member function. More specifically, a user defined conversion into the function pointer type.

```
    State p;
```

Declares the member that was initialized in the constructor.

```
};

State_ state_start(StateData& d);
State_ state_selecting(StateData& d);
State_ state_initializing(StateData& d);
State_ state_tracking(StateData& d);
```

Free functions, that can be pointed by a `State`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand the "operator" function. Can you explain it more? @user2079303

Comment: @AnitaW.Smith what about it do you not understand? Did you study user defined conversions?

Comment: Never heard it before. I will search it. If it is easy to explain for this case, can you briefly tell me what it does? @user2079303

Comment: @AnitaW.Smith it allows you to implicitly convert a `State_` into a `State`. Like this: `State_ s(state_start); State fun_ptr = s;`

Comment: Worth adding that it's the only way to write a function that returns it's own address (or a function with the same signature). Without the struct middle-man, you'll get infinite recursion.

Answer (score 3):

`State_` is a structure type.

`State` is a pointer to function, accepting a parameter of type `StateData&` and returning `State_`.

`typedef a b;` defines a type `b` which is exactly the same as `a`.

`p` is a field of class `State_`, `pp` is a parameter of the constructor. `p(pp)` is a special syntax for constructor only, initializing `p` to the value of `pp`

Answer (score 1):

This one declares a struct with name StateData

```
struct StateData;
```

The typedef keyword is use create a new alias for a type
Example:

```
typedef int mynumber; /// mynumber is an alias of type of int 
mynumber number = 3; /// so you can do this (number is a type of int just the int name is different)
```

one advantage of this is you can easily change the data type of the number variable specially if you have massive instances of mynumber:
Example:

```
typedef int mynumber;
mynumber number1 = 3;  
mynumber number2 = 4;
mynumber number3 = 5; 
// what if you want to make all this type of double? or a float? easy
// just change the int to a double or float like this
    typedef float mynumber;
    typedef double mynumber;
```

This one declares a struct with name State_

```
struct State_;
```

This one defines State_ that was declared above.

```
struct State_
{
    State_( State pp ) : p( pp ) { }
    operator State()
    {
        return p;
    }
    State p;
};
```

This one is list initializing the `p`. it initializes the `p` that was declared 
inside the struct (i,e. `State p`);

```
State_( State pp ) : p( pp )
{ 
}
```

These prototype functions returns State_ that accepts reference to StateData

```
State_ state_start(StateData& d);
State_ state_selecting(StateData& d);
State_ state_initializing(StateData& d);
State_ state_tracking(StateData& d);
```

Answer (score 1):

typedef helps when defining pointer to function. You have a function with following header. State_ is the return type and the input is a reference to StateData.

```
State_ function (StateData&)
```

Then just add star (and parens to resolve precedence) to describe a pointer to this function.

```
State_ (*State) (StateData&)
```

Then put typedef in front of that to define it as a new type. Now you have a new type which can be used at other places. typedef is used to create type aliases which makes your code more readable.

```
typedef State_ (*State) (StateData&)
```

Now this type State can be used in another places. Declare a new variable `p` using this new type

```
State p
```

Use new State type as input to the constructor

```
State_(State pp)
```

Being able to specify pointer-to-function types using typedef make writing functions that take other functions as input much readable.

Comment: C++ question, reading C books is not gonna do anyone any good if it's a beginner

Comment: I have removed reference to the book from the question.